# Dummary Variable numeric difference in SAS

Tags: sas

My code was running fine until I added the last line for age 5+. Does anyone know what's wrong with that line? Thank you.

```
data  Work.File ;

set Work.File;

Female =(Sex ='F');
Male = (Sex ='M');
Age1=(age=1);
Age2=(age=2);
Age3=(age=3);
Age4=(age=4);
Age5+=(age='5+');


run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of a SAS variable has certain restrictions, you can't have a + sign. Also Age should be a numeric variable. You can write last line as:

```
Age5Plus=(age>=5);
```

Comment: See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm

Comment: oh in my data, it is actually called 5+ , so I don't think 6,7,8 etc

Comment: Is age a character variable in your data?

Comment: It works now after changing 5+ to 5plus. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
"Age5+"n=(age>=5);
```

would also work after setting

```
options validvarname=any;
```

but than you have to escape that name every time you use that variable